# Multiple fields search form without duplicating the component for each search condition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a multiple fields form and each field is used to search through an API which would display a table below with the data found matching the search. I have it working for one field. But I need it to work for all fields in the form. I just don't know how to make this dynamic so I don't have to repeat my component 10 times.

Let me show the relevant code:

```
  <form class="uk-form-stacked">
    <div>
       <input-field label="Product ID" v-model="id"></input-field>
       <input-field label="Product Name" v-model="name"></input-field>
       <select-field label="Supplier ID" v-model="supplierId" :options="supplierOptions"></select-field>
       <select-field label="Category ID" v-model="categoryId" :options="categoryOptions"></select-field>
       <input-field label="Quantity Per Unit" v-model="quantityPerUnit"></input-field>
       <input-field label="Unit Price" v-model="unitPrice"></input-field>
       <input-field label="Units in stock" v-model="unitsInStock"></input-field>
       <input-field label="Units on order" v-model="unitsOnOrder"></input-field>
       <input-field label="Reorder level" v-model="reorderLevel"></input-field>
       <checkbox-field label="Discontinued" v-model="discontinued" :options="this.discontinuedOptions" :checked="checked"></checkbox-field>
    </div>
    <div>
       <button type="reset" class="uk-button uk-button-secondary uk-button-small" @click.prevent="clearForm"> Clear </button>
       <button type="submit" @click.prevent="search" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small"> Search </button>
    </div>

    <div class="results-area">
       <result-item
          :data="filteredResultsById" // can this be made to accept a conditional computed value?
          :total-pages="Math.ceil(filteredResultsById.length / 10)"
          :total="filteredResultsById.length"
          :per-page="10"
          :current-page="currentPage"
          @pagechanged="onPageChange"
       />
    </div>
  </form>

  computed: {
      ...mapGetters(["getProducts"]),
      filteredResultsById: function() {
         return this.getProducts.filter((result) => {

            // I imagine there should be a loop in here maybe?
            let resultById = result.id;
            return resultById.toString().match(this.id);
         });
      },
  },
```

So, this works for the first field (Product ID) but I need to make the other fields searchable too and I don't want to replicate the component like this

```
    <div class="results-area">
       <result-item
          :data="filteredResultsById"  // <-- By Id
          :total-pages="Math.ceil(filteredResultsById.length / 10)"
          :total="filteredResultsById.length"
          :per-page="10"
          :current-page="currentPage"
          @pagechanged="onPageChange"
       />
       <result-item
          :data="filteredResultsByName" // <-- By Name
          :total-pages="Math.ceil(filteredResultsByName.length / 10)"
          :total="filteredResultsByName.length"
          :per-page="10"
          :current-page="currentPage"
          @pagechanged="onPageChange"
       />
       <result-item
          :data="filteredResultsBySupplierId"  // <-- By supplierId
          :total-pages="Math.ceil(filteredResultsBySupplierId.length / 10)"
          :total="filteredResultsBySupplierId.length"
          :per-page="10"
          :current-page="currentPage"
          @pagechanged="onPageChange"
       />
       ...

       
    </div>
```

Likewise, it is repetitious to have 10 similar computed methods. How can I improve this?

Separate issue - I have it that it works as the v-model changes by interpolation, which is cool and all but I want to make it on click of the save button, but again, I don't want to make 10 dynamically shown buttons. That's insane.

### Edit

So I figured out how to make it so that I don't have to replicate the component 10 times! Here's the edited computed method now. I feel like a switch statement would probably be less expensive on render so it doesn't render all of these conditions. Am I right about that?

Anyhow, I am still having an issue getting this to work onclick from the search button and also I can't search by the `<select>` value in a dropdown

```
filteredResults: function() {
  return this.getProducts.filter((result) => {
    let resultById = result.id;
    let resultByName = result.name;
    let resultBySupplierId = result.supplierId;
    let resultByCategoryId = result.categoryId;
    let resultByQtyPerUnit = result.quantityPerUnit;
    let resultByUnitPrice = result.unitPrice;
    let resultByUnitsInStock = result.unitsInStock;
    let resultByUnitsOnOrder = result.unitsOnOrder;
    let resultByReorderLevel = result.reorderLevel;
    let resultByDisc = result.discontinued;
    return (
      resultById.toString().match(this.id) &&
      resultByName.match(this.name) &&
      resultBySupplierId.toString().match(this.supplierId) &&
      resultByCategoryId.toString().match(this.categoryId) &&
      resultByQtyPerUnit.toString().match(this.quantityPerUnit) &&
      resultByUnitPrice.toString().match(this.unitPrice) &&
      resultByUnitsInStock.toString().match(this.unitsInStock) &&
      resultByUnitsOnOrder.toString().match(this.unitsOnOrder) &&
      resultByReorderLevel.toString().match(this.reorderLevel) &&
      resultByDisc.toString().match(this.discontinued)
    );
  });
},
```

Comment: As I can see all fields are independent that means you have to write ONE method/computed prop that takes into account all non-empty fields to build a composite filter expression for `getProducts`.

Comment: I wouldn't be totally against writing a computer property for each of the 10 search fields as long as I can make the views and search button dynamic. I still think the computer method can be written dynamically. I just can't think anymore. But all the data is coming from the same API endpoint

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should rename `filteredResults` function into `getFilteredResults`, add `filteredResults` as an array to a `data` section and in `search` function do somethng like this:

```
<result-item
  :data="filteredResults"
  :total-pages="Math.ceil(filteredResults.length / 10)"
  :total="filteredResults.length"
  :per-page="10"
  :current-page="currentPage"
  @pagechanged="onPageChange"
/>
...
methods: {
  search () {
    this.filteredResults = this.getFilteredResults()
  }
  reset () {
   // clear all fields here
   ...
   this.filteredResults = []
  }
}
```